# How to display Google Map in an Android app using Xamarin

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am designing an android app with Xamarin which will have an activity with google maps inside it, but i am struggling  to display the map. It shows an empty box with no map display on it. Following is the code which i used for this practice.

```
My Activity

namespace teslin
{
    [Activity(Label = "Map")]
    public class MpActivity : Android.GoogleMaps.MapActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
           SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MapView);
           var map = FindViewById<MapView>(Resource.Id.mapv);
           map.Clickable = true;
           map.Controller.SetZoom(16);
          map.Controller.SetCenter(new GeoPoint((int)40.8270449E6, (int)-73.9279148E6));
}}

xml lay out

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_weight="9" />
        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapv"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:apiKey="AIzaSyD-UMij5IO6ezjuFCNnF7tRoG3niaPbNEU" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using the obsolete/outdated [Maps API v1](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/index). Google removed support for this last year.

Instead you want to use [Android Maps API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) (a part of Google Play Services). Xamarin has [some documentation](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/) on Maps in Android. It can be a bit tricky to get Maps working in Android, so carefully read these docs. Specifically, you'll want to read the section on the [Maps API](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/part_2_-_maps_api/).

There is [an example on Github](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/MapsAndLocationDemo_v3) that shows how to use the [Google Play Services Component](http://components.xamarin.com/view/googleplayservices) to add Maps to your application.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for a thorough example, check out this [video](http://youtu.be/W6Q0olRPsus) that demonstrates how to integrate Google Maps with Xamarin Android, hope this helps!